# Inno Setup - Dynamic positioning of controls/checkboxes

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I have a bunch of checkboxes on a page, and all of those are conditionally visible, and the `Top` position is defined relative to the previous checkbox, e.g.

```
CheckBox4.Top := CheckBox3.Top + CheckBox3.Height + 5;
```

When at least  one of the components is set to be invisible, the result looks like this:

[image: Gap]

What I'd like the checkboxes to do, is to shift upwards, if the previous one is set to invisible. `Prog3` should be right underneath `Prog1`, or, if both `Prog2` and `Prog3` are hidden, `Prog4` should be right underneath `Prog1`.

---

EDIT: My code after the answer:

```pascal
var
  PageNameLabel,PageDescriptionLabel: TLabel;
  TypesComboOnChangePrev: TNotifyEvent;
  UninstallConfigssPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallNextButton: TNewButton;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
  Dirs: TStringList;

procedure UpdateUninstallWizard;
begin
  UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := CustomMessage('UninstPNL');
  UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := CustomMessage('UninstPDL');
  UninstallNextButton.Caption := CustomMessage('UninstBtn');
  UninstallNextButton.ModalResult := mrOK;
end;  

procedure UninstallNextButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UninstallNextButton.Visible := False;
end;

procedure AddDirCheckbox(Path: string; Caption: string);
begin
  if DirExists(Path) then
  begin
    Dirs.Add(Path);
    CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(Caption, '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
var
  PageText: TNewStaticText;
  PageNameLabel,PageDescriptionLabel: string;
  CancelButtonEnabled: Boolean;
  CancelButtonModalResult: Integer;
begin
  if not UninstallSilent then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.Caption := CustomMessage('Uninst');

    UninstallConfigssPage:= TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallConfigssPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallConfigssPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallConfigssPage.Align := alClient;

    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallConfigssPage;
    PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
    PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left - ScaleX(20);
    PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
    PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
    PageText.AutoSize := True;
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.Caption := CustomMessage('UninstTxt');

    Dirs := TStringList.Create();
    CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(UninstallConfigssPage);
    CheckListBox.Parent := UninstallConfigssPage;
    CheckListBox.SetBounds(PageText.Left,ScaleY(30),PageText.Width,ScaleY(220));
    CheckListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    CheckListBox.Color := clBtnFace;
    CheckListBox.MinItemHeight := ScaleY(20);

    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Alien Shooter'), 'Prog1');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Theseus'), 'Prog2');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Alien Shooter Revisited'), 'Prog3');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Alien Shooter 2'), 'Prog4');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Alien Shooter 2 Reloaded'), 'Prog5');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Alien Shooter 2 Conscription'), 'Prog6');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Zombie Shooter'), 'Prog7');
    AddDirCheckbox(ExpandConstant('{app}\Zombie Shooter 2'), 'Prog8');

    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallConfigssPage;

    PageNameLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
    PageDescriptionLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;

    UninstallNextButton := TNewButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallNextButton.Parent := UninstallProgressForm;
    UninstallNextButton.Left := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Left - UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width - ScaleX(35);
    UninstallNextButton.Top := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Top;
    UninstallNextButton.Width := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width + ScaleX(30);
    UninstallNextButton.Height := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Height;
    UninstallNextButton.OnClick := @UninstallNextButtonClick;
    UninstallNextButton.TabOrder := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.TabOrder - 1;

    UpdateUninstallWizard;
    CancelButtonEnabled := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;
    CancelButtonModalResult := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult;
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;

    if UninstallProgressForm.ShowModal = mrCancel then Abort;

    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := CancelButtonEnabled;
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := CancelButtonModalResult;

    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := PageNameLabel;
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := PageDescriptionLabel;

    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallProgressForm.InstallingPage;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You have to explain us when/how the checkboxes are set invisible. Is that also dynamic? = Can the visibility change while the installer is running? Show us the code.

Comment: It's just `DirExists`. `CheckBox1.Visible := DirExists(SomeDir)`. Nothing Should change when the Uninstaller is running.

Comment: So why do you even create the invisible checkboxes? Why don't you use `TInputOptionWizardPage`? It would maintain the layout for you.

Comment: `TInputOptionWizardPage` - I have no idea how to use the values of individual checkboxes here, nor am I sure if this can be used during Uninstall.
Visibility of the checkboxes is based on existance of Config folders for each of the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TInputOptionWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputOptionWizardPage), which is designed for this kind of tasks/layouts. Create it using [`CreateInputOptionPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage).

Use [`TStringList`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStringList) (or `array of string`) to maintain association between the created checkboxes and the paths.

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  Dirs: TStringList;

procedure AddDirCheckbox(Path: string; Caption: string);
begin
  if DirExists(Path) then
  begin
    Dirs.Add(Path);
    Page.Add(Caption);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpWelcome, 'Configuration files found', 'Choose an action for configuration files',
      'Choose the configuration files you''d like to be deleted.', False, False);
  Dirs := TStringList.Create();
  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir1', 'Prog 1');
  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir2', 'Prog 2');
  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir3', 'Prog 3');
end;
```

To process the selected checkboxes/paths, use a code like this:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    for Index := 0 to Dirs.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Page.Values[Index] then
      begin
        MsgBox(Format('Deleting %s', [Dirs[Index]]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Assuming `C:\dir1` and `C:\dir3` exist and `C:\dir2` does not, you will get:

[image: Check list box]

---

If you cannot use `TInputOptionWizardPage`, e.g. because you need the checkboxes on an uninstaller form or on a custom form, just create the [`TNewCheckListBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox) (what `TInputOptionWizardPage` uses internally).

The following example places the `TNewCheckListBox` on a blank custom `TWizardPage`, but you can of course place it, wherever you want.

```
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
  Dirs: TStringList;

procedure AddDirCheckbox(Path: string; Caption: string);
begin
  if DirExists(Path) then
  begin
    Dirs.Add(Path);
    CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(Caption, '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page :=
    CreateCustomPage(
      wpWelcome, 'Configuration files found',
      'Choose an action for configuration files');
  Dirs := TStringList.Create();
  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
  CheckListBox.Parent := Page.Surface;
  CheckListBox.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  CheckListBox.Height := Page.SurfaceHeight;

  { The same styling as used by TInputOptionWizardPage }
  CheckListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  CheckListBox.Color := clBtnFace;
  CheckListBox.WantTabs := True;
  CheckListBox.MinItemHeight := ScaleY(22);

  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir1', 'Prog 1');
  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir2', 'Prog 2');
  AddDirCheckbox('C:\dir3', 'Prog 3');
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    for Index := 0 to Dirs.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if CheckListBox.Checked[Index] then
      begin
        MsgBox(Format('Deleting %s', [Dirs[Index]]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it was clear from the screenshot. The page in question is the first page of Uninstall, not Setup.

Comment: It does not really matter, use `TNewCheckListBox` instead of `TInputOptionWizardPage`.

Comment: So, I have this going on: `Prog1Box := ProgsBox.AddCheckBox(CustomMessage('prog1'), '', 0, False, DirExists(ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\DaleByte\Prog1')), False, False, nil)`. This doesn't really hide the checkbox, it just grays it out. Also, how do I use the state of this checkbox?

Comment: So do not add it, if you do not want it. As my `AddDirCheckbox` function shows.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to create either of those pages during Uninstal...

Comment: Just place the `CheckListBox` to your "uninstall" page. `CheckListBox.Parent := ...`. - We cannot help you further, as you didn't show us your code! The uninstaller does not have any pages. You must have developed those pages! And you have placed the checkboxes there, so place the `CheckListBox` the same way!

Comment: I usually don't post code, since people keep asking me to remove it as irrelevant. Anyway, added code.

Comment: Replace `CheckListBox.Width := UninstallConfigssPage.Width;` with `CheckListBox.Width := UninstallConfigssPage.ClientWidth;` (and more tweaking is needed to layout it correctly) + Similarly for `Height`

Comment: Still empty. Are we sure `TNewNotebookPage` knows what `Add` is?

Comment: Your code works for me. What if you remove the styling code (`BorderStyle` and `Color`)? Show us a screenshot then. - No idea what you mean by your question about `Add`.

Comment: I had 1 wrong line. Posted the new code. Works perfectly, as always. Sorry, I was a little bit thick there. Thanks, for sticking with me.