# Check if multiple folders exist in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a custom uninstall page, which is invoked with this line:

```pascal
UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallConfigsPage;
```

Now, this just shows the page every time the uninstaller is run, but I need it to show only if certain folders exist (there's 6 of them). I could make an `if` statement with a bunch of `or`'s, but I'm wondering if there's a neater way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there's no better way than calling [`DirExists`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_direxists) for each folder:

```pascal
if DirExists('C:\path1') or
   DirExists('C:\path2') or
   DirExists('C:\path3') then
begin
  // ...
end;
```

---

Though, when processing a set of files/folders, it's advisable to have their list stored in some container (like [`TStringList`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStringList) or `array of string`), to allow their (repeated) bulk-processing. You already have that (`Dirs: TStringList`) from [my solution to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44251985/850848#44254371).

```pascal
var
  Dirs: TStringList;
begin
  Dirs := TStringList.Create();
  Dirs.Add('C:\path1');
  Dirs.Add('C:\path2');
  Dirs.Add('C:\path2');
end;
```

```pascal
function AnyDirExists(Dirs: TStringList): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Dirs.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if DirExists(Dirs[I]) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Result := False;
end;
```

---

But I know from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44251985/850848), that you map all the paths to checkboxes. Hence, all you need to do, is to check, if there's any checkbox:

```pascal
if CheckListBox.Items.Count > 0 then
begin
  UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallConfigssPage;

  // ...

  if UninstallProgressForm.ShowModal = mrCancel then Abort;

  // ...

  UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallProgressForm.InstallingPage;
end;
```