# Read check box list state by individual checkbox caption

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I have several conditionally visible checkboxes, which means that their index isn't static. In this case, tying an action to e.g. `CheckListBox.Checked[0]` is useless, since `0` is a different checkbox every time. Is there a way to see if a checkbox with caption `foo` is checked?

I'm trying to do this:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    if CheckListBox.Checked[0] then
      DelTree(ExpandConstant('{appdata}\Dagonybte\Prog1'), True, True, True)
    if CheckListBox.Checked[1] then
      DelTree(ExpandConstant('{appdata}\Dagonybte\Prog2'), True, True, True)
      { ... }
    if CheckListBox.Checked[2] then
      DelTree(ExpandConstant('{appdata}\Dagonybte\Prog3'), True, True, True)
  end
end;
```

Comment: Won't `CheckListBox.Items.IndexOf('Item caption')` help to find the index?

Comment: Can you give us some background? What do you need it for specifically? [My answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254371/850848) shows you how to process the checkboxes.

Comment: You actually keep asking similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44274005/850848 - It looks like you are looking at the problem from a wrong side - So what do you want to do, once you get a reference to the check box? Show us some code! Looking up a checkbox by its caption looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I don't post code, bc people on SO kept asking me to remove it/stick to the point/truncate the quetion or sometimes even delete the question....  Added the code.

Comment: Your code just confirms that you do not need to lookup the checkbox by its caption. See my answer for correct solution.

Comment: Maybe you had a history of posting irrelevant code, but in your recent questions you have always posted a good example. Keep doing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up a checkbox by its caption looks like a terrible idea.

It's indeed doable:

```pascal
Index := CheckListBox.Items.IndexOf('Prog 1');
if (Index >= 0) and CheckListBox.Checked[Index] then
begin
  { checked }
end
  else
begin
  { does not exist or unchecked }
end;
```

But it's not the right approach.

The purpose of [`TCheckListBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox) is to allow generating a list of checkboxes from some data, in a loop. What is indeed the [way you are using it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44251985/850848).

Your attempt to lookup the checkbox by its caption indicates, that you want to write a code dedicated for each checkbox. That defies the purpose of the `TCheckListBox`.

---

Instead, when processing a user selection, use the same approach, as when generating the list, use a loop.

The [code I have shown you to generate the checkbox list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44251985/850848#44254371), generates by purpose a list of associated paths with the same indexes in `Dirs: TStringList`.

So iterate that list along with the checkboxes to process the paths:

```
{ Iterate the path list }
for Index := 0 to Dirs.Count - 1 do
begin
  { Is the associated checkbox checked? }
  if CheckListBox.Checked[Index] then
  begin
    { Process the path here }
    MsgBox(Format('Processing path %s', [Dirs[Index]]), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    { In your case, you delete the folder }
    DelTree(Dirs[Index], True, True, True);
  end;
end;
```

The above is actually similar to the code, you already have in my previous answer.

And it's the same concept, I have shown you in your yet another question: [Inno Setup - Check if multiple folders exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44274005/850848).

---

In case individual checkboxes really require a special processing (i.e. they do not represent a list of qualitatively same items), the right way is to remember their index at the time you generate them:

```
if ShouldAddItem1 then
  Item1Index := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(...)
else
  Item1Index := -1;

if ShouldAddItem2 then
  Item2Index := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(...)
else
  Item2Index := -1;
```

```
if (Item1Index >= 0) and CheckListBox.Checked[Item1Index] then
  { Process item 1 }

if (Item2Index >= 0) and CheckListBox.Checked[Item2Index] then
  { Process item 2 }
```

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was not familiar with either `CheckListBox` or `TCheckListBox` before you offered the solution, so, trying to figure out how they work resulted in stupid questions. It's all clear now. Let me know if I should delete any irrelevant questions.

Comment: No it's ok. These are not bad questions. Note that even, if you stayed with standalone `TCheckBox`'s, you should have done the same - maintain a list of paths and associated checkboxes to allow them to be processed in a loop.